# Custom font in Apple Watch simulator doesn't show

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, apple-watch

I'm making a simple Apple Watch app, using Objective-C, and I'm trying to use a custom font.

I have added the font to the info.plist, and also the supporting files folder. The font does work in the storyboard, but when I run the app in the simulator it's just the regular system font. Any ideas?

(I haven't used any code to set up the font)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the custom font file in **both** your WatchKit extension bundle **and** the WatchKit app bundle? The reason for this is you need to be able to create strings with the font at runtime (via the WatchKit extension), then the information is sent to Watch and the font from the WatchKit app's bundle is used to render the string on Watch.

Then it's simply a case of adding it to the `UIAppFonts` key in your Info.plist file as you mentioned.

Apple has documentation on using custom fonts, found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html).

Hope this helps!

J

Comment: If you go to the font file, just tick your extension and app in 'Target Membership' via the right-hand pane in Xcode while you have the font file selected. This should copy it to the extension/app bundle when built. You're right, too - doing this will also add it to 'Copy bundle resources'. You can drag the files into this for each target but I find it's easier to just tick two boxes under Target Membership!